# Don't award popular question badge for bad questions

Tags: feature-request, badges, popular-question

I had a bad (downvoted) question; now I got a [Popular Question badge](https://superuser.com/help/badges/26/popular-question) for it, which is kinda funny. Please consider not awarding a Popular Question badge for bad questions.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is downvoted. It's a surprisingly good idea to disable popularity badges on bad questions. After all, it's not something we want to promote and not something to be proud of.

Comment: @Mast I think it's because people read the previous title of this question and thought this was a request to award badges for bad questions.

Comment: This makes sense. Maybe a criterion that the question be positively scored can be added for it to be eligible for the Popular Question badge?

Answer (score 12):

I have a better idea. It's a popular question because many other people have the same or a similar problem and find the question via search engines. Why don't you edit the question in a better shape, so that future visitors can be helped more quickly? That's the purpose of Stack Exchange sites, to build a library of good Q&A about [insert topic here].

Comment: I suppose this works for most sites, but how about those where answer invalidation is a serious concern?

Comment: That's definitely something to keep in mind when editing, but 'in a better shape' is deliberately vague. Without seeing the question, one can't tell whether it's downvoted because of unclear language, rantyness, lack of details, etc...